# Use Meteor to send email with multiple FROM addresses

Tags: email, meteor, smtp

I'm trying to use Meteor to send emails to multiple recipients. I want each email to show the other recipients in the `to` and `cc` field as usual. But I want each to be  sent with a different `from` and `reply-to` address.

I assume it's not possible to specify a `from` for each `to`, but can I maybe do multiple sends, each with recipients listed that aren't actually delivered?

What I mean is, can I send one email to Tom, with Dick and Harry listed as CCs, but have it not actually delivered to Dick or Harry. Then in a different send, with a different from address and through a different SMTP server, send a message to Harry with Tom and Dick listed as CCs?

Answer (score 1):

Using a service like Mandrill, yeah it would be possible. You would just have to write some logic that goes something like:

```
var sendTo;
var emails = [];

// assign the sendTo based on whatever you're doing

if(sendTo == 'Tom'){
    emails = ['one@domain.com','two@domain.com'];
    for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++){
         sendEmail = function() {
            return Meteor.Mandrill.send({
                to: 'yourreceiver@domain.com',
                from: emails[i],
                subject: subject,
                html: html
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The reason for that loop is that Mandrill will not send to multiple emails at once, it has to be singular emails to multiple people.

Forgot to say this requires the mandrill package https://atmospherejs.com/wylio/mandrill

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't looked into Mandrill. But I'm not sure your example does what I'm looking for. What I need, I think, is to include recipients in the email, so the receiver sees them, but not actually send those emails. So if I send to tom@foo.com, with CCs for dick@bar.com and harry@baz.com. Dick and Harry never receive anything, but if Tom hits reply-all, those emails will be in the CC field of his reply.

Comment: In that case you would just need to add the emails to a key called "replyTo"

Comment: Not really. The purpose is that I want to message both internally and through email; so Tom can make a message to Dick, and CC Harry. If Harry is another internal user, I don't want to send him an email through SMTP, it's just an internal message. But Dick, who's not an internal user, should be sent an email. That much I can do, but what I can't do is get the email to Dick to show harry@myservice.com in the CC field of the email. I don't want an email to be delivered to harry@myservice.com, but I want him in the CC of the email to Dick. Does that make sense? Is that possible?

Comment: In the case above, the replyTo would be Tom <tom@myservice.com>, who sent the message.